# Turn off implicit dependency injection in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I am trying to debug a missing provider in a large-ish AngularJS project.  The error is a missing 'dProvider'.  It is only occurring on a version of the code that is minified, which makes sense, because we have no 'd' controllers, factories, or services.  I am having trouble finding what is causing this, and searching through the minified code for things like `function(a,b,c,d)` hasn't yielded anything yet.  Is there any way to force only explicit dependency injection in Angular?  It seems like if I could force this I could catch the problem in the dev environment.

Comment: try generating a source map file during your minification process - that way you should be able to determine the name of the missing provider  [here is a arcticle on sourcemaps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

Comment: This could happen if you forgot to min-safe an injection. If you don't have a 'd' service it sounds like your parameters got mangled.

Comment: I hadn't thought of source maps.  That's a good idea, but according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719780/source-maps-with-grunt), source map generation with grunt is probably beyond what I'm able to do for the moment.  I understand why i could get an error like this, I'm just having trouble finding it.  I'm also not confident a source map would help, because the stack trace only lists functions within angular.js, not my minified code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yippee! Since [Angular 1.3.1](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) you can turn off implicit dependency injection!

From code, using `strictDi` config property:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], {
    strictDi: true
});
```

Or from template, using `ng-strict-di` directive:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
```

Comment: I just happy to inform about it!

Answer (score 0):

Wow that sucks.

It's probably a controller/service defined like this

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
     ...
})
```

instead of the safer

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    ...
}])
```

I don't have a fool-proof answer but maybe you can search for *', function(* and if you get lucky you'll find the culprit. If something like that doesn't work, source maps are probably the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's what I've been looking for.  that or a different number of function parameters than defined dependencies...

Comment: You could also beautify your minified code (with jsbeautifier.org/ for example‎) and that might help you identify the line that causes the problem. Although, if I remember correctly, that error doesn't give a line in your own code :(

Comment: Yeah, that's the main problem.  I could get from a minified version of my own code to the solution.  But it's only listing angular.js stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up selectively commenting out portions of my html until I determined where the issue was occurring.  Turns out it was an [angular-ui-bootstrap issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/pull/671).